# Matlab inverse of (non linear) system transformation

Tags: matlab

I have a system that looks something like this:

```
z1 = 5*x1 + x2*cos(x3)
z2 = x1*sin(x3) + 3*x2
z3 = 3*x1 - 2*x2
```

which is the transformation of a system of differential equations (just to give some context, I don't think you really need to know this). Now I would like to find the inverse of this transformation which would look something like:

```
x1 = ...(stuff with z1, z2, z3)...
x2 = ...
x3 = ...
```

now I guess with this system it is relatively easy to find it manually but I have to do the same thing with a 7 variable 7 equation system and it would get pretty tedious to do.
I cannot find a way to get Matlab to do this, can anybody help?

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily mathematically possible in most cases. Even with just 1 equation like `z1 = cos(x1)`, you can't find a function `x1 = f(z1)` because in the original equation many values of `x1` give the same value of `z1`. (i.e. cos(0) = 1 and cos(2*pi) = 1)

Comment: Very true, but in this case `x1, x2...` and `z1, z2...` have no specific value, so you can find an inverse function it just might have a different domain. Also I am assuming that since they are all dynamics of a physical system it should always be possible to find an inverse otherwise you would brake physics...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could work:

You could get an approximate solution by taylor expanding the trigonometric functions and then doing Gaussian elimination.

Gaussian elimination can be done using rref in Matlab if the problem can be put on the form (using random numbers):

x+3y+4z = 5

2x+y+6z= 4

8x+2y+7z=3

Then Ax=b, A=[1 3 4;2 1 6;8 2 7], b=[5;4;3]

To find x do: E=[A b]
x=rref(E)

EDIT: Sorry, I see now that you don't have numbers for z1, z2.. so this is not really a solution for your case.